# cycle a text in jquery over time

Tags: javascript, jquery, time, setinterval

I have a disperate need of help. :)

I need to make a jquery script where a text is shown in a div and change over an a determinated amount of time.
so, for example every 7 seconds the div content changes (i have to insert also a fade in fade out effect).
so i've write this code but it doesn't work

```
var caption = [
"Tip 01",
"Tip 02",
"Tip 03",
"Tip 04",
"Tip 05",
];

setInterval(function() {
    jQuery.each(caption, function() {
        $("#message-box").html(caption[i]);
    });
    }, 7 * 1000);
```

where I'm wrong?
All of this because supersized plugin doesn't support caption on images so I have to do this manually in this way.

## message-box is the div where che array items will be shownd.

thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use like this

```
var i = 0;
setInterval(function() {       
$("#message-box").html(caption[i]);
i++;
if (i == caption.length){i=0;}
}, 7 * 1000);
```

[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Dineshkani/X8uXN/)

Comment: why "i == caption.length" ? why not a modulo? var l = caption.length; and you access it like caption[i%l]

Comment: why use modulo? what is the difference in condition check you given??

Comment: it works! thanks but why does it start after 7 seconds? when the site loads nothing is show until the first 7 seconds

Comment: @user1071936 Change your code to what you want. see here http://jsfiddle.net/Dineshkani/X8uXN/1/

Comment: why if I use the fadeToggle the content of the array is first showed then fade out and than fade in?

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this

```
var caption = ["Tip 01", "Tip 02", "Tip 03", "Tip 04", "Tip 05"];
var l = caption.length; // array length (here 5)
var i = 0; // set to 0 (array index starts at 0)

setInterval(function () {
    if (i > l) i = 0; 
    // when i is bigger than the total values in the array set it back to 0
    $("#message-box").html(caption[i]); // insert text from array
    i++; // add + 1 to i
}, 7000);
```

`$.each()` will display directly the last value in the array and not switch between them

Comment: thanks but it doesn't work even on jfiddle

Comment: @user1071936 yeah the array had an extra `,` which caused the code to break. I fixed it now